# Unable to connect to remote TFS server from VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

**SOLVED**: Turns out the people not being able to access TFS via VS2010 were using laptops, I didn't put two and two together, and Symantec Endpoint was blocking the ports required.

---

Some users cannot get to the TFS 2010 server, secured by SSL, from team explorer but can via IE.

For example, I go into VS2010 SP1 and attempt to add a new server, it sits there for a while and then spits out a dialog that basically tells me "Unable to connect to the remote server". If I enter the exact same URL into IE I get access perfectly.

So

https://tfserver:8088/tfs (custom SSL port number) in IE and I get full access 

The same detail entered into the add server results in

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use a proxy to connect to your TFS server?  What happens if you enter the fully-qualified domain name instead of just the short name?

Comment: Thanks for your help, just turned out to be Symantec Endpoint being too smart for it's, or our rather, own good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to tfspreview through VS2010, you need to install following things :

VS SP1: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23691

KB2581206: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=39070

Edit: These links are no longer available. The update is now only provided through windows update. See here

KB2662296: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2662296